# What is the best practice for closing a connection from within a server endpoint?

Tags: java, sockets, tyrus

I have a custom configurator set up that grabs the cookie and processes it. The output is added to the user properties on the config.

In the `@OnOpen`-annotated method, I compare that value with a value from the path. If there is a mismatch, then I want to close the socket, with a 1008, Violated Policy reason.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I could:

1. Manually call the `@OnClose` method, passing the reason
2. Throw an exception and let `@OnError` be invoked
3. Something else?

I'd like the socket to be closed and Tyrus to clean up the resources. I've looked over the documentation, but didn't see an answer to how resources are cleaned up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

never invoke `@OnClose` manually - that won't accomplish anything.

See [`Session.close(CloseReason)`](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs-javax.websocket/1.1/javax/websocket/Session.html#close(javax.websocket.CloseReason)).

Comment: Thanks. So, would best practice be to call `Session.close` instead of throwing something like a `NotAuthorizedException` (which is how I would deal with this in a REST service).

Comment: WebSocket API does not have ExceptionMappers like JAX-RS, but.. if you want to throw an exception, you can - @OnError will be invoked and then you should handle this by calling Session.close(..).